# Issue with Inheriting the same interface in multiple classes

Tags: c#, interface

When inheriting the same interface in multiple classes, does it not have the problem up updating all the classes with the implementation of the interface ? For instance if I have an interface which is implemented by 4 classes and may be more in the future and if I add any method to the interface which is implemented by only one of the 4 classes then, would it not be a tedious task to go and implement all the rest of the classes with a not implemented exception or something..? I know you might question why cant I add that method to the class itself, the reason is I am using a factory here and I return the reference of the interface with one of the objects of these classes. Any ideas on how I can go about this kind of an approach ? Is there an alternative approach to this kind of situation ?

Adding the sample code for the above scenario

```
 public interface ITest
{
    string TestMethod1(string st, int ab);
    int TestMethod2(string st);
    void TestMethod4(int ab);
    float ITest.TestMethod3(string st);
}
public class Class1 : ITest
{
    public string TestMethod1(string st, int ab)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    public void TestMethod4(int ab)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int TestMethod2(string st)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public float TestMethod3(string st)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
 public class Class2 : ITest
{

    float ITest.TestMethod3(string st)
    {
        return float.Parse("12.4");
    }

    void ITest.TestMethod4(int ab)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public string TestMethod1(string st, int ab)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int TestMethod2(string st)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
 public class Main
{
    ITest test = null;

    public ITest CreateFactory(TestType testType)
    {
        switch(testType)
        {
            case TestType.Class1:
               test = new Class1();
                break;
            case TestType.Class2:
                test = new Class2();
                break;
        }
        return test;
    }
}

enum TestType
{
    Class1,
    Class2
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you need another interface rather than modifying the first one. The idea of adding a member that would throw an exception in all but one implementation sounds wrong to me.

Comment: so that means, I add an interface for each class then ? because there might be changes in other classes too in the future.

Comment: The point of an interface is exactly that *all* classes implementing it share the same members. Thus if you want to add some member to the interface you have to do so for all classes. But as Charles already mentioned you can also define an interface - e.g. `IExtendedInterface` - that only the new class implements and that derives from the already existing interface adding some new members.

Comment: See this for some discussion on issues relating to not implementing methods of an interface : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208235/not-all-interface-members-will-be-implemented

Comment: Making breaking changes causes more work for you. This isn't unique to interfaces. Or C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For instance if I have an interface which is implemented by 4 classes and may be more in the future and if I add any method to the interface which is implemented by only one of the 4 classes then, would it not be a tedious task to go and implement all the rest of the classes with a not implemented exception or something..?

An interface is a contract. If you are expecting that some classes will not be able to comply with the contract then they should not declare that they do. Implementing the interface to simply throw `NotSupportedException` or `NotImplementedException` should be a last resort; there are usually better and cleaner solutions.

The solution in your case is to simply declare a new interface:

```
public interface IFrobbable //legacy version
{
     void Frob()
}

public interface IFrobbableOnSteroids: IFrobbable //the new and improved frobbable wonder
{
     void MegaFrob();
}
```

Your new improved implementations should implement `IFrobbableOnSteroids`. Notice that this new interface implements itself `IFrobbable`; this means that any object implementing `IFrobbableOnSteroids` would be usable both in "legacy" code (only aware of `Frob`) and in updated code (aware of `MegaFrob`). This has the nice property that you don't break existing client code.

Of course you could also simply make the new updated class implement *both* interfaces, but I personally prefer to make one interface include the other.

"Legacy" classes that will not be lucky enough to be improved will remain as simple and mortal `IFrobbable`s, but that is the way it should be. If you are not a `FrobbableInSteroids`, don't pretend to be one; as the saying goes in my country (free translation), "easier to catch a liar than a crippled".

*UPDATE:*

Concerning your question about a factory method, well, considering that your classes seem to be public, there is no real reason for an `enum`. Just use generics and the types themselves:

```
public static T CreateFrobbable<T>()
    where T: IFrobbable, new()
{
    return new T();
}

public static T CreateFrobabbleOnSteroids<T>()
    where T: IFrobbableOnSteroids, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
```

And now, if we have a class `SomeFrobbable: IFrobbable`, you would create one simply calling `CreateFrobbable<SomeFrobbable>()`. And a `SomeFrobbableOnSteroids: IFrobbableOnSteroids` could be created either as an `IFrobbable` with `CreateFrobbable<SomeFrobbableOnSteroids>()` or as a full fledged `IFrobbableOnSteroids` with `CreateFrobbableOnSteroids<SomeFrobbableOnSteroids>()`. What you wouldn't be able to do, and thats a good thing, is `CreateFrobbableOnSteroids<SomeFrobbable>() //Compile time error`.

Comment: +1 for both the answers, however, I have  a little difficulty in doing that, adding a new interface is fine, but as I already mentioned, I am doing this to support factory pattern, where I instantiate one of the classes and return a reference of the interface, now adding a new instance means the reference returned will not have the new members in it correct ?

Comment: @Blossom Well your factory should know how to provide both types: If you ask for an `IFrobbable` then you should return an `IFrobbable` independently of whether it is truely an `IFrobbable` or an `IFrobbableOnSteroids`. On the other hand if you ask for an `IFrobbableOnSteroids` then by all means return one. Those that can only be `IFrobbable` will only be that. The others can be both, its up to the consumer to decide which flavour of the object he wants.

Comment: yes, that is exactly what my concern is, I have added sample code to my question, will you be able to help me with how can I modify the factory if I added another interface in this case? I have been struggling to find a solution for this approach.

Comment: thank you for the answer and your time. this is not completely the answer to my problem, but it surely gives me the idea..very grateful to you..

Answer (score 2):

Making changes to an existing API is allready tedious and needs many changes to existing clients of your API. However *adding* new members is bit easier as you can simply introduce a new interface that adds the new functionality:

```
interface ITheInterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

Now create a new interface deriving from the existing one:

```
interface ITheInterface2: ITheInterface
{
    void DoSomething2();
}
```

A common - but not neccessarily the best - practice is to just use a number after the interface-name indicating its version - here `2` and marking the old one `Obsolete` to indicate there´s a newer version. IMHO it´ll be better to add some name indicating what the new interface actually does this is the new functionality.

Now all your existing classes can still implement `ITheInterface`, while new ones implement the new interface. So you don´t need to change existing code but can consume new members if you implement that new interface.